# Is there such a thing as a SAAS Bulk Emailer?

Tags: email, saas

I'd like to periodically send out email to a large number of subscribers.

I envisage a system where I invoke a web service, sending across the list of email addresses to send to and the message body, for a scheduled sending, with the SAAS provider worrying about IP reputation, throttling etc.

Does such a service exist?

Thanks

Comment: You're asking if there is a free web service you can use for unlimited spamming?

Comment: Not at all. I wish to send out email users have subscribed to, but I want to avoid the hassle of configuring and managing an SMTP server. I may be going about this the wrong way - I am looking for some direction on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/) is free for a limited number of subscribers and very reasonable prices for larger lists. I highly recommend them.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of email service companies out there.  Your best bet is to find what one works best for you for the coast. Some charge by contacts that you have, some go by how many emails you send out each month.

If you have a lot of contacts, but you don't send out emails to everyone each time.  Take a look at: getResponnce, streamsend, or jangomail.

However if you send out a lot of emails to everyone, and you don't have tons of contacts, take a look at: Constant contact or campainer.  They don't require a cap on your contacts list

Answer (score 0):

Problem with all these mailers like mailchimp is that they do not work. All emails either go to the 'Promotion' inbox or worst, the spam mail.

https://bytebix.com/why-you-should-not-use-mailchimp-sendinblue.html